# I need to know which is this font (latex)

Tags: fonts

i'm writing an essay, and i would like to write with these fonts in math style.. (see the image below). Anyone know it? Thank you :)

[image]

Comment: run `pdffonts <document>` or load the pdf into the Adobe Reader and look into the list of fonts.

Comment: Do you know if this specimen was typeset with (La)TeX? The font is a Times Roman clone. Somewhat uncommon shapes for the bold **v** and the `\partial` symbol, though.

Comment: It's not a million miles away from [Monotype Imprint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imprint_(typeface)).

Comment: @Mico from the spacing of the fractions and the large parens it does not look like TeX output.

Comment: @Thruston:   italic $p$ and $m$ seem different from `Imprint`. For me, it's close to `xcharter` – available in TeX Live or MiKTeX.